Python import bs4 Python 3.12.5
I have installed bs4
pip install beautifulsoup4
I imported it
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
And when i try to execute my code i get this error code:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\..\..\main.py", line 2, in <module> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
I realy dont get what the problem is, i installed bs4
First i tried :
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
After what i tried
import bs4
I tried
pip install beautifulsoup4
And then
pip install bs4
And still not working

Do you use virtualenv or venv? If so, check if you have activated environment.

Hello, i just installed virtualenv using pip install virtualenv, where do i activate the environment? @MilosStojanovic

Check out docs for virtualenv https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html
You don't have to use virtualenv, but if you do and if you install bs4 into virtual environment (for which you have to activate it first), whenever you want to use it, you have to activate environment again.
